# How to enable audio of two ffplay windows simultaneously?(How can I hear audio of the video files at the same time?)

Tags: c++, c, windows, ffmpeg, sdl

When more than one ffplay-window is running only the audio of one of them is enable , But I need to hear all of them at the same time.

For example I run two command-lines separately like this:

```
//command line 1
ffplay -i video1.avi

//command line 2
ffplay -i video2.avi
```

How can I hear audio of the video files at the same time?

I did not find anything about that in the ffplay documents, So I want to change the ffplay source code.

this is `event_loop` function (in ffplay.c):

```
static void event_loop(VideoState *cur_stream)
{
SDL_Event event;
double incr, pos, frac;

for (;;) {
    double x;
    refresh_loop_wait_event(cur_stream, &event);
    switch (event.type) {
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        if (exit_on_keydown) {
            do_exit(cur_stream);
            break;
        }
        switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
        case SDLK_ESCAPE:
        case SDLK_q:
            do_exit(cur_stream);
            break;
        case SDLK_f:
            toggle_full_screen(cur_stream);
            cur_stream->force_refresh = 1;
            break;
        case SDLK_p:
        case SDLK_SPACE:
            toggle_pause(cur_stream);
            break;
        case SDLK_m:
            toggle_mute(cur_stream);
            break;
        case SDLK_KP_MULTIPLY:
        case SDLK_0:
            update_volume(cur_stream, 1, SDL_VOLUME_STEP);
            break;
        case SDLK_KP_DIVIDE:
        case SDLK_9:
            update_volume(cur_stream, -1, SDL_VOLUME_STEP);
            break;
        case SDLK_s: // S: Step to next frame
            step_to_next_frame(cur_stream);
            break;
        case SDLK_a:
            stream_cycle_channel(cur_stream, AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO);
            break;
        case SDLK_v:
            stream_cycle_channel(cur_stream, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
            break;
        case SDLK_c:
            stream_cycle_channel(cur_stream, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
            stream_cycle_channel(cur_stream, AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO);
            stream_cycle_channel(cur_stream, AVMEDIA_TYPE_SUBTITLE);
            break;
        case SDLK_t:
            stream_cycle_channel(cur_stream, AVMEDIA_TYPE_SUBTITLE);
            break;
        case SDLK_w:
    #if CONFIG_AVFILTER
            if (cur_stream->show_mode == SHOW_MODE_VIDEO && cur_stream->vfilter_idx < nb_vfilters - 1) {
                if (++cur_stream->vfilter_idx >= nb_vfilters)
                    cur_stream->vfilter_idx = 0;
            } else {
                cur_stream->vfilter_idx = 0;
                toggle_audio_display(cur_stream);
            }
     #else
            toggle_audio_display(cur_stream);
     #endif
            break;
        case SDLK_PAGEUP:
            if (cur_stream->ic->nb_chapters <= 1) {
                incr = 600.0;
                goto do_seek;
            }
            seek_chapter(cur_stream, 1);
            break;
        case SDLK_PAGEDOWN:
            if (cur_stream->ic->nb_chapters <= 1) {
                incr = -600.0;
                goto do_seek;
            }
            seek_chapter(cur_stream, -1);
            break;
        case SDLK_LEFT:
            incr = -10.0;
            goto do_seek;
        case SDLK_RIGHT:
            incr = 10.0;
            goto do_seek;
        case SDLK_UP:
            incr = 60.0;
            goto do_seek;
        case SDLK_DOWN:
            incr = -60.0;
        do_seek:
                if (seek_by_bytes) {
                    pos = -1;
                    if (pos < 0 && cur_stream->video_stream >= 0)
                        pos = frame_queue_last_pos(&cur_stream->pictq);
                    if (pos < 0 && cur_stream->audio_stream >= 0)
                        pos = frame_queue_last_pos(&cur_stream->sampq);
                    if (pos < 0)
                        pos = avio_tell(cur_stream->ic->pb);
                    if (cur_stream->ic->bit_rate)
                        incr *= cur_stream->ic->bit_rate / 8.0;
                    else
                        incr *= 180000.0;
                    pos += incr;
                    stream_seek(cur_stream, pos, incr, 1);
                } else {
                    pos = get_master_clock(cur_stream);
                    if (isnan(pos))
                        pos = (double)cur_stream->seek_pos / AV_TIME_BASE;
                    pos += incr;
                    if (cur_stream->ic->start_time != AV_NOPTS_VALUE && pos < cur_stream->ic->start_time / (double)AV_TIME_BASE)
                        pos = cur_stream->ic->start_time / (double)AV_TIME_BASE;
                    stream_seek(cur_stream, (int64_t)(pos * AV_TIME_BASE), (int64_t)(incr * AV_TIME_BASE), 0);
                }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        break;
    case SDL_VIDEOEXPOSE:
        cur_stream->force_refresh = 1;
        break;
    case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        if (exit_on_mousedown) {
            do_exit(cur_stream);
            break;
        }
    case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
        if (cursor_hidden) {
            SDL_ShowCursor(1);
            cursor_hidden = 0;
        }
        cursor_last_shown = av_gettime_relative();
        if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) {
            x = event.button.x;
        } else {
            if (event.motion.state != SDL_PRESSED)
                break;
            x = event.motion.x;
        }
            if (seek_by_bytes || cur_stream->ic->duration <= 0) {
                uint64_t size =  avio_size(cur_stream->ic->pb);
                stream_seek(cur_stream, size*x/cur_stream->width, 0, 1);
            } else {
                int64_t ts;
                int ns, hh, mm, ss;
                int tns, thh, tmm, tss;
                tns  = cur_stream->ic->duration / 1000000LL;
                thh  = tns / 3600;
                tmm  = (tns % 3600) / 60;
                tss  = (tns % 60);
                frac = x / cur_stream->width;
                ns   = frac * tns;
                hh   = ns / 3600;
                mm   = (ns % 3600) / 60;
                ss   = (ns % 60);
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_INFO,
                       "Seek to %2.0f%% (%2d:%02d:%02d) of total duration (%2d:%02d:%02d)       \n", frac*100,
                        hh, mm, ss, thh, tmm, tss);
                ts = frac * cur_stream->ic->duration;
                if (cur_stream->ic->start_time != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
                    ts += cur_stream->ic->start_time;
                stream_seek(cur_stream, ts, 0, 0);
            }
        break;
    case SDL_VIDEORESIZE:
            screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(FFMIN(16383, event.resize.w), event.resize.h, 0,
                                      SDL_HWSURFACE|(is_full_screen?SDL_FULLSCREEN:SDL_RESIZABLE)|SDL_ASYNCBLIT|SDL_HWACCEL);
            if (!screen) {
                av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Failed to set video mode\n");
                do_exit(cur_stream);
            }
            screen_width  = cur_stream->width  = screen->w;
            screen_height = cur_stream->height = screen->h;
            cur_stream->force_refresh = 1;
        break;
    case SDL_QUIT:
    case FF_QUIT_EVENT:
        do_exit(cur_stream);
        break;
    case FF_ALLOC_EVENT:
        alloc_picture(event.user.data1);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

}

But I can not find the command that cause disable audio when change active window or lost focus in `event_loop` function.

Comment: so if you play them separate, you hear them, but when you play them together you only hear one?

Comment: No ,Always I can hear only the sound of the active window. (the ffplay window that has focus).

Comment: if you only run one and it is not in focus do you still hear it? I'm trying to imagine what would cause this

Comment: @rogerdpack  thanks ,  yes I can hear audio when is running only one instance of ffplay  even if it has not focus.

Comment: It's possibly some limitation in SDL would be my guess.  See Stoyan's answer for how to combine them.

Comment: related: https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2734&p=8887&hilit=sdl#p8887

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple input files for ffplay and then "map" different streams together, but if you have alsa mixer as default audio device the system should mix the audio automatically for you. Modifying ffplay is not a trivial task

this is how you select output device
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#Examples-7

this is how you "concatinate" mutiple inputs:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate

Comment: But the `-map` works for ffmpeg only .
(my question is about the ffplay for windows).

Comment: or the "amerge" or "amix" filters I suppose... "-map" should work with ffplay as well, though not sure how, gl!

Comment: @rogerdpack and @Stoyan Ivanov   ,  If you think that `-map` will work to ffplay please answer these my questions: [Q1](https://superuser.com/questions/978446/how-to-use-the-lavfi-trim-filter-in-ffplay-command-line)  and   [Q2](https://superuser.com/questions/978143/how-to-change-pts-for-a-part-of-a-video-file-with-ffplay)   - Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest asking on the ffmpeg-user mailing list, GL!

Comment: never tried ffplay on windows can't help much this is probably a SDL/Windows question not a ffmpeg/ffplay one

Comment: Here is a short discussion on SDL on windows and background audio: http://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?t=35223